# Renaming API fieldname causing problems in Flow

Tags: fields, flow

I noticed an issue regarding updating field API names and the use in Flows.

Any changes in API names are automatically 'refactored' in flow. i.e., assignments, use in decision elements and screens is updated as expected. Nothing wrong, great!

But when referencing the field at runtime (when running the interview) the field seems unaccessible, the flow returns an error like this:

```
UPSERT --- UPSERT FAILED ---  ERRORS :  (INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE) Case: bad field names on insert/update call: *field api name* ---  for SFDC record with ID : null
```

The first time this happened I spend considerable time trying to figure out how this is possible, only to find out that after 15 - 60 minutes the problem solved itself.

Does anyone know whether this is a known problem? Right now everytime I update a field API name working in Flow, I take a long coffee break.

Comment: As a best practice I would always recommend *against* renaming API name...ever.

Comment: You are absolutely 100% right. However, these fields are rarely used as mergefields in code, and because we have a high number of flows running in the org, it is more preferable to rename instead of making new fields and replace them all.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem.

To immediately solve the problem all I did was save the flow as a new version and activate it and that did the trick.

Comment: Saving as a new version or even as a new flow didn't work for me. I had to completely delete the flow and recreate it. This solved it for me. Thankfully it was a simple flow.